# Issue with Tab index for Prime ng datatables sort icon

Tags: angular5, primeng

I've used the prime ng data table in my application.
In that, I want to use tab index for sort icon(**`<p-sortIcon>`**) but it's not working. can anyone help me with this??
this is how I used in code [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWasV.png)

And displaying as below,  once I enter tab, got focus there but I'm unable to do sorting using the keyboard.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUFKs.png)

Comment: Please update your question by adding your code. Then community will get an idea on what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please check once now

Comment: can you use tabindex with p-sortIcon ?

Comment: I've used on <p-sorticon> but it's not working. like `<p-sortIcon [tabindex]="24" field="controls.serialNumber.value"></p-sortIcon>`

Comment: Why do you need to use tabindex?

Comment: For ease of access throughout the page. By using the keyboard I want to control the focus.

Comment: Any other possibilities to achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

Try this friend.

`[attr.tabindex]="1"`

Comment: It's not working, It's getting focus but sorting is not working.

Comment: is it getting focus the column?

Comment: Yes, the focus is getting but when the enter key is pressed sorting is not working.
Normally, when the enter key is pressed sorting is working but the problem is when I give tab index manually it's not working.

Comment: What is happening when the mouse clicked?

Comment: sorting is working when the mouse clicked. But I want to use the enter key to sort.

Comment: Inside that sort icon, there is an anchor tag we should give tab index to that, then it is working but it is appending after the page load. how can I add a tab index to that...??

Answer (score 0):

why dont you go with primeng default modules....

```
https://primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/sort
```

Comment: I've used the default modules only. But I've used tab index for sort icon manually.

Comment: `<p-sortIcon [tabindex]="24" field="controls.serialNumber.value"></p-sortIcon>`
This is how i used, before this data table i've fields and have different tab index.